# rails - structuring models (like common models in a directory instead of too many files in models directory)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As of now, I know this: We can create a model by placing a model file in app/models directory.

So, if I want to create 3 models User, UserProfile, Transaction, then I have 3 files:

```
app/models/user.rb  
app/models/user_profile.rb  
app/models/transaction.rb
```

What I want to have is:

app/models/user/ directory should contain all models related to User or auth etc.

so can we do this ? Is this the right  way ?

Answer (score 0):

i think that it is possible to do that. the only thing that you will have to make sure that all the files in your user directory will have to be namespaces with user

```
module User
  class UserProfile
  end
end
```

i don't think that it is possible to do that with the `User` class actually, as it would be a Module and a Class.

what you have to keep in mind though, i don't think that you should do it unless it is really REALLY really important to do that. so you should have a good excuse to violate a convention in rails. if there is a reason for that, just go ahead. if not, just don't do it.